# mongodb sorted by conditional element in a array

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a demand looks a little complex:

I have a collection in which the document has a array called `startTimeArray`  stored the timeStamps of a event. Such as:

```
"startTimeArr" : [
    NumberLong("1425340800000"),
    NumberLong("1425513600000"),
    NumberLong("1426032000000"),
    NumberLong("1425427200000")
]
```

I want the find result to be sorted by **the minimum Time stamp that greater than the current time**(ie, time has not passed yet, the minimum on ).for example, if current time stamp in millisecond is `1425513500000` then the time stamp participate in the sorting action of this document is `1425513600000`, which is the minimum stamp of the `startTimeArr` array that are greater than `1425513500000`.

So The element of `startTimeArr` participate in the sorting action should be the one:

1. greater than the current time.
2. the minimum one that meet with #1

I *guess* I can do this with a aggregate such as:

```
 db.event.aggregate(
    {
      $match:{
         startTimeArr:{
              $gt: 1425513500000 // presume the current time is 1425513500000
           }
      }
    },
    {
      $group:{
          _id:"$_id", minTimeStamp:{?????} // and I don't know what to write here.
      }
    },
    {
      $sort:{minTimeStamp:1}
    }
 )
```

But I cant get a clue of how to write the `minTimeStamp` calculation.

Could you tell how to do this? Or if there are other ways to do this, will be appreciated too.

---

Since the problem is a bit too complex, I will just put some samples and outputs expected as required.

If we have 3 document like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("537d98c20cf2264603faf0eb"),
  "name": "Let's go to LA",
  "fee": 500,
  "duration":2,
  "startTimeArr":[
    NumberLong("1425310000000"),
    NumberLong("1425320000000"),
    NumberLong("1425330000000"),
    NumberLong("1425380000000")
   ]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("537caa7e0cf2264603faf0e9"),
  "name": "Let's go to NewYork",
  "fee": 800,
  "duration":3,
  "startTimeArr":[
    NumberLong("1425320000000"),
    NumberLong("1425330000000"),
    NumberLong("1425340000000"),
    NumberLong("1425350000000")
   ]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("537c5ec50cf2264603faf0e7"),
  "name": "Let's go to Washington",
  "fee": 700,
  "duration":2,
  "startTimeArr":[
    NumberLong("1425350000000"),
    NumberLong("1425360000000"),
    NumberLong("1425370000000"),
    NumberLong("1425390000000")
   ]
}
```

And if current time is `1425300000000` then the time participate the sorting will be:

```
 LA         1425310000000
 NewYork    1425320000000
 Washington 1425350000000
```

So the find result of these three documents will be sorted as the order `LA, NewYork, Washington`

But when time moves on and the current time is  `142534000000` then the time participate the sorting procedure will be:

```
LA         1425380000000
NewYork    1425350000000
Washington 1425350000000
```

So the find results expected to be sorted as the order `NewYork, Washington, LA`.

Comment: Could you please write more clearly what exactly do you want to get. Right now you are telling about find and doing aggregate which confuses me.

Comment: sorry about that, I'll try to edit, to make things more specific.

Comment: do you want the results in the startTimeArr to be sorted or all documents to be sorted?

Comment: @SalvadorDali all the document, in fact the `startTimeArr` is already sorted.

Comment: @armnotstrong To help me understand your problem more clearly, can you post some sample documents and the expected output/result?

Comment: @chridam hi, I have just edit the question and hope that explained the question, please check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @armnotstrong Thanks for updating your question, much clearer now. Looking into it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the aggregation operator you're missing is [`$min`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/), which can be used in a `$group` step in your aggregation. You'll also need to `$unwind` the array of start times before grouping:

```
var timeNow = 1425300000000;  // set the time cut off for testing

db.event.aggregate(
    // Find documents with matching events
    // Note: could take advantage of an index to limit results
    { $match: {
        startTimeArr:{
            $gt: timeNow
        }
    }},

    // Convert start time array to stream of docs
    { $unwind: "$startTimeArr" },

    // Limit to matching array elements
    { $match: {
        startTimeArr:{
            $gt: timeNow
        }
    }},

    // Find the minimum timestamp in each matching document
    { $group:{
        _id:"$_id",
        name: { $first: "$name" },
        minTimeStamp:{ $min: "$startTimeArr" }
    }},

    // Sort in order of minimum timestamp (ascending)
    { $sort: { "minTimeStamp" : 1 }}
)
```

Sample output:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("537d98c20cf2264603faf0eb"),
      "name": "Let's go to LA",
      "minTimeStamp": NumberLong("1425310000000")
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("537caa7e0cf2264603faf0e9"),
      "name": "Let's go to NewYork",
      "minTimeStamp": NumberLong("1425320000000")
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("537c5ec50cf2264603faf0e7"),
      "name": "Let's go to Washington",
      "minTimeStamp": NumberLong("1425350000000")
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: Hi Stennie, thanks for answer, but I find that the sorting element which expected to be different according to different `timeNow` kept the same and so the result's order are kept the same http://pastebin.com/B2g7Z4dB

Comment: @armnotstrong Sorry, there was a missing `$match` step after the `$unwind`. Edited to fix.

Comment: It works! thank you, but can I get the output as the raw document rather than only the field that was grouped? ie, with `fee` and `duration` etc, but  I don't want to specific every field in `$group`(since the fields may be change and added with demands grows)

Comment: If you don't want to list all the fields in the `$group` step you can use the [`$$ROOT` variable](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) (available in MongoDB 2.6+). For example, replace `name: { $first: "$name" }` in the `$group` with  `fields: { $first: "$$ROOT" }`. If you find yourself doing a lot of manipulation to get the common output you're after, you might want to rethink your schema to better accommodate these queries. FYI: [Storing large arrays with unbounded growth](http://askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays) can be a performance anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) aggregation operator within the $group pipeline stage in order to get the minimum timestamp from the `startTimeArr` array values. However, you need to first deconstruct the `startTimeArr` array field from the filtered input documents (using a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator) to output a document for each element using the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator. In the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage, the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator enables you to bring back the other fields in your grouping that you can later project at the end. Thus your aggregation pipeline would look like this:

```
var date = new Date(),
    timestamp = +date;

db.event.aggregate([
    {
      "$match": {
         "startTimeArr": {
              "$gt": 1425300000000 // or use the timestamp variable to get the actual current timestamp
           }
      }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$startTimeArr"
    },
    {
      "$group": {
          "_id":"$_id", 
          "minTimeStamp": {
              "$min": "$startTimeArr"
          },
         "name": { "$first": "$name" },         
         "fee": { "$first": "$fee" },
         "duration": { "$first": "$duration" },
      }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": 1,
            "minTimeStamp" : 1,
            "fee": 1,
            "duration": 1
        }
    },
    {
      "$sort": { "minTimeStamp": 1 }
    }
]);
```

**Output**:

```
 /* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "minTimeStamp" : NumberLong(1425310000000),
            "name" : "Let's go to LA",
            "fee" : 500,
            "duration" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "minTimeStamp" : NumberLong(1425320000000),
            "name" : "Let's go to NewYork",
            "fee" : 800,
            "duration" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "minTimeStamp" : NumberLong(1425427200000),
            "name" : "Let's go to Washington",
            "fee" : 700,
            "duration" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks chridam, the `$unwind` operand really give me a clue. And instead of just get the grouped field, is there any way that I can get the raw document as an output? Meanwhile I put  just the word `LA, NewYork, Washington` there just for convince, no strugle to cut the output like that, sorry if any misleading.

Comment: And it seemed that whatever the current time is, the result will always keep sorting with the minimum element of each `startTimeArr`, http://pastebin.com/DwZ8njAe   and  http://pastebin.com/B2yKzxGt